# SharePoint adding massive attributes to divs each time I check in a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to help a friend troubleshoot some strange javascript issues in SharePoint 2010, but I'm confused so far.

I have a simple page with several divs, each of which has a header and starts displayed. Some simple jQuery adds an event handler to the header such that when it is clicked, the text of its matching div is hidden. This all seems to work fine. However on checking in changes to a page, very large attributes are added to each div that seem to correspond with some sort of jQuery event handler. This happens every time a page is checked in (a new attribute is added each time there is a check-in, not replacing the old one).

For example, in one div, as one of checkin:

```
jquery110106221769366327998="47"
```

appears. Since there have been several checkins, there are tons of these. Other divs are populated with lots of 'sizzle' attributes like below.

```
sizzle-1386877979872="[object Object]"
```

A div either has sizzle or jquery attributes but not both. The 'sizzle' attributes have only been appearing as of a few months ago, it was only jquery before.

I found a similar problem at [Sharepoint 2010 / Jquery - Multiple attributes added in content Editor webpart edit / save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14640365/sharepoint-2010-jquery-multiple-attributes-added-in-content-editor-webpart-e), however the only answer seems to be fairly messy script solution that does not seem to address the root of the problem.

Has anyone run into this issue before / have a sense of where these attributes are coming from and how to prevent them? They seem to be serving very little tangible purpose, and make pages large and tedious to edit. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you edit the page and remove the jquery tags and sizzle tags, then save and edit again: did they disappear? I think that, when you edit the page, the jQuery and/or Sizzle scripts run and add the tags. After that when you save the page, Sharepoint keeps the tags added by the JavaScript script. How to resolve? Maybe in changing your code to avoid having the scripts running when editing the page or something like that...

Comment: Yep. So the lifecycle of them is that when a page is saved (checked-in) a new set of attributes is added, in addition to the already existing ones. So even if I were to go in and delete all the existing `jquery1527562343="45"` attributes, a new set is re-created when the page is saved.